# Custom Validation in InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath

I want to restrict users from entering a value greater than 60 in InfoPath form. How do I accomplish?...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a validation rule for this. When users try to save form, they will get an error message.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]